# Player name #s not sequencing correctly from NetworkIdentity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, networking

Something strange is happening every time a player gets spawned on the server with regards to its name. I'm using the function below to assign a unique name to each player on the server based on the player's network identity. It seems to be working fine but there are gaps in the player numbers that get assigned.

What I mean by that is when a single player connects it gets names Player1. When that same single player disconnects and then reconnects it gets named Player8. Why wouldn't it get named Player2? This is the only player that's ever connecting while I'm testing it.

```
 public override void OnStartServer()
    {
        NetworkInstanceId playerUniqueID = GetComponent<NetworkIdentity>().netId;
        playerUniqueName = "Player_" + playerUniqueID;
        gameObject.transform.name = playerUniqueName;
    }
```

Comment: Hard to tell from what you've provided here . . . but NetworkIdentity could be used by lots of parts of the program for lots of things.  If things are multithreaded or there is any delay or a call to other APIs . . . others around you could be consuming additional values.

Comment: Ah, I see, that makes sense. Thank you!